# Retorno de un objeto en Realm

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

estoy teniendo problemas con un objeto que me devuelve en Realm , lo extraño es que si printo por consola el objeto si que me lo printa bien pero sin embargo si intento acceder a su valor me dice que esta vacio .
La estructura del objeto es el siguiente:

```
class Favourite : Object {
    var character : Character!
}
```

1. Creo un objeto y lo añado a la BD

   ```
   let fav = Favourite()
   fav.character = character
   FavouriteDao.sharedInstance.addFavourite(characterFavourite: fav)
   ```
2. Obtengo todos los objetos de tipo favourite

   func getAllFavourites() -> Results {
        return realm.objects(Favourite.self)
    }
3. Cuando obtengo el elemento y hago un print

   ```
   Favourite {
   character = Character {
       name = Spider-Man;
       descriptionC = Bitten by a radioactive spider, high school student Peter Parker gained the speed, strength and powers of a spider. Adopting the name Spider-Man, Peter hoped to start a career using his new abilities. Taught that with great power comes great responsibility, Spidey has vowed to use his powers to help people.;
       thumbnail = Thumbnail {
           id = 815D93D0-C116-4267-978C-9E47C0074D0D;
           path = http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/3/50/526548a343e4b;
           extensionImage = jpg;
       };
   };
   ```
4. Si intento acceder al elemento character me dice que esta a **nil**

Alguien logra entender por que si hago un print del objeto favourite me muestra que hay dentro un objeto character pero sin embargo si intento acceder a el me dice que no existe ??

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que lo que le falta es el atributo *dynamic* a la propiedad character. De esta manera:

```
class Favourite : Object {
   dynamic var character : Character!
}
```

Comment: Tienes razón , muchas gracias pensé que las propiedades que contenian objetos no era necesario!

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado! :). Las propiedades _List_  y _RealmOptional_ son las que no deben ser _dynamic_  pero las normales si ;)